# Ugly 2 dimensional list. Why?

Tags: python-3.x, list, code-cleanup

I'm trying to figure out why my list looks ugly when printed:

```
alfa = []
alfa.append([])
alfa.append([])
a = 0
a = float(a)
print("Input the points, one per line as x,y.\nStop by entering an empty line.")
while a == 0:
    start = input()
    if start == '':
        a = a + 1
    else:
        alfa[0].append(start.split(",")[0:1])
        alfa[1].append(start.split(",")[1:2])
print(alfa)
```

with input of:

```
2,3
12,56
1,2
a
```

I get this:

```
[[['2'], ['12'], ['1']], [['3'], ['56'], ['2']]]
```

While if i try this simple Program found online:

```
elements = []

elements.append([])
elements.append([])

elements[0].append(1)
elements[0].append(2)

elements[1].append(3)
elements[1].append(4)

print(elements[0][0])

print(elements)
```

I get this:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Why is this result much tidier than mine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
alfa[0].append(int(start.split(",")[0]))
alfa[1].append(int(start.split(",")[1]))
>>>[[2, 12, 1], [3, 56, 2]]
```

You're getting the quote marks because `input()` is interpreting the input as a string. It doesn't know that you want what you've typed to be a number, so it has to handle it in a default way. You have to tell the code that the input should be interpreted as an `int`.

Secondly, you're slicing the arrays when you use `[0:1]` to get an array consisting of the entries from 0 to 0, which is the same as getting element 0 directly, except you get an array with one element rather than just the element you want. Essentially, you are inserting `[2]` rather than `2`.

Answer (score 1):

The data from your input is strings, as shown by the quotation marks.  Cast your strings to integers after the input.  If you want to have the [1, 2] formatting without the extra brackets then you need to place numbers in alfa[0] and alfa[1] etc..

```
alfa = []
alfa.append([])
alfa.append([])
a = 0
a = float(a)
print("Input the points, one per line as x,y.\nStop by entering an empty line.")
while a == 0:
    start = input()
    if start == '':
        a = a + 1
    else:
        alfa[0].append(int(start.split(",")[0]))
        alfa[1].append(int(start.split(",")[1]))
print(alfa)
```

Oh, I see @Andrew McDowell has beat me to this.  Well here you go anyway...